# Want to improve debugging of component on VB6 Watch screen

Tags: visual-c++, vb6

Maybe I have been doing too much C#, but I thought it was somehow possible to see a "default" property or function value on an object variable when it is unexpanded. The value would appear next to the "+" on the watch pane.

The reason is that I am trying to improve debug capability of one of our objects. We recently added an improvement to see all the of the object's name - value pairs by adding a method with dispid -4 to the C++ object which returns an iterator object supporting IEnumVARIANT, returning variants containing an array of 2 variants. ArrayValue(0) is the Name; ArrayValue(1) is the Value.

Unfortunately, when we look at the watch window, we still have to spend time clicking on a whole load of pluses until we find the correct value. Better - but still not yet ideal.

Does anybody have any ideas?

**[Addendum]**
I have just thought of another work-around for C++ components, but I am not sure how easy this would be. Perhaps the component could add expanded property names - one for each "name" value?

Answer (score 3):

Setting the property's procedure id to `(Default)` does it for a VB6 created class. I think this is dispid 0.

Comment: Sadly, I tried this previously, and the objects in my array didn't show the default value.

Comment: Very interesting. The object immediately in the Watch pane shows the default property in grey to the right of the "+" sign, as I specified. However, any objects under the object being watched do not show the default, nor do any of the items in the Locals pane.

Comment: Useful... I expect you're in the area of "here be dragons" :P

Comment: I suppose that the only work-around would be to write an add-in to add a context menu item to arrayItem(0), arrayItem(1), arrayItem(2) etc.

Comment: I can't get it to show the default value for enumerated collection members either, while it does for the same object added expliclty and accessing an specific collection index. Sorry :(